# Generate SAML 1.1 (and possibly 2.0) assertions

Tags: web-services, security, single-sign-on, token, saml

I'm looking for a very easy and quick way to generate some SAML assertions. This is only going to be used for testing (using SOAP UI). So I just need something that can generate a valid assertion, signed or unsigned, that I can then drop into SOAPUI and send off to my Web Service. I know how to add the assertion to the SOAP message and all that other good stuff, I just need some valid test assertions.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will find one. SAML has so many profiles/bindings. It's almost impossible to generate a single assertion that meets requirement of every relying party.

Your best bet is to capture a real assertion and use it as a template. Just replace the field on the fly in SOAPUI.

This is the approach used by Google SSO client library (now deprecated). You can find the examples here,

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-sso-sample/downloads/list